# how to understand this recursion algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

```py
def sum(a):
    if a==1:
        s=1
    else:
        s=1+2*sum(a-1)
    return s
```

function:calculate the sum of the sequence of number. Its common ratio is 2, last term is `2^( a-1)` and first term is `1`.

Why does it use `s=1+2*sum(a-1)` to  implement the function?

Comment: Naming a function `sum` is terrible, because it overrides the builtin `sum` -- if a teacher gave you this function as a homework assignment, I advise finding a new teacher if at all possible.  :0

Comment: To be honest, this implementation seems wrong. For a=3, you'd expect the sequence to be `1, 2, 4, 8`, but the result of running `sum(3)` is 7. What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe I misremembered the function. I totally don't understand how it works

Comment: We can't answer your question without knowing what `sum` is supposed to compute.

Comment: @Mureinik There's a `1 +` in front.

Comment: With the information you have provided, there's no particular reason why `s = 1 + 2*sum(a - 1)`; it's just how the function happens to be defined. Whether this definition computes what `sum(a)` is *supposed* to compute is another question.

Comment: so you are studying about arithmetic formulas ?

Comment: i just asked my classmate and corrected the function.

Comment: @ombk im learning about recursion . My homework requires to use it but I can only use circulation to finish it :(

Comment: @Mureinik i believe u did ur recursion wrong

Comment: @ombk I copied the code provided here and ran it.

Comment: @Mureinik if the goal is to get the sum of values from 1 to 2^(a-1), then this is right.  For `a == 3`, the sequence is `(1, 2, 4)` and the sum is 7.  Think of it in binary, doubling the prior result binary shifts left one bit, adding 1 makes the last bit 1.  Essentially, this is building a bit string of length `a` filled with 1's, which will, in fact, be `2^a - 1`.

Comment: @pjs with the latest edit to the question, this now makes sense

Comment: @Mureinik Agreed that it didn't make sense prior to the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sum1(a):
    if a==1:
        s=1
    else:
        s=1+2*sum1(a-1)
    return s
```

What this function does, let's take `a=4`.

(1) `s = 1 + 2*sum1(4-1) = 1 + 2*sum1(3) = 1 + 2*s2`

(2) `s2 = 1 + 2*sum1(3-1) = 1 + 2*sum1(2) = 1 + 2*s3`

(3) `s3 = 1 + 2*sum(2-1) = 1 + 2*sum(1) = 1 + 2*s4 = 1+2 = 3`

`Going BackWard :`  `(3 * 2 + 1 ) * 2 + 1 = (7) * 2 + 1 = 15`

Do it for bigger numbers, you will notice that this is the formula of `2^a - 1`.

***Print `2^a` and `2^a - 1`***

```
Difference: (4, 3)
Difference: (8, 7)
Difference: (16, 15)
Difference: (32, 31)
Difference: (64, 63)
Difference: (128, 127)
Difference: (256, 255)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.I clearly know how does it work now. But I wonder how I can write it out. For example, I need to use recursion to calculate n! but i don't know what statement should use after the "else" . I appreciated it if you can give me some advice

Comment: @Zhongyi That would be a new and different question.

Comment: @pjs this is basically math, you have to prove that `2X_(n-1) + 1` is equivalent to `2^a - 1`

Comment: @ombk Yes, I know.  See my comment on the question itself.

Comment: @Zhongyi https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885822/solving-a-recurrence-formula enjoy the proof ^_^

Answer (score 0):

@Zhongyi I'm understanding this question as asking "*how does recursion work*."

Recursion exists in Python, but I find it a little difficult to explain how it works in Python. Instead I'll show how this works in [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/) (a [Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)) dialect).

First, I'lll rewrite `yoursum` provided above into `mysum`:

```py
def yoursum(a):
    if a==1:
        s=1
    else:
        s=1+2*yoursum(a-1)
    return s


def mysum(a):
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    return 1 + (2 * mysum(a - 1))

for i in range(1, 11):
    print(mysum(i), yoursum(i))
```

They are functionally the same:

```
# Output
1 1
3 3
7 7
15 15
31 31
63 63
127 127
255 255
511 511
1023 1023
```

In Racket, `mysum` looks like this:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (mysum a)
  (cond
    ((eqv? a 1) 1)
    (else (+ 1 (* 2 (mysum (sub1 a)))))))
```

But we can use language features called [quasiquoting and unquoting](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html) to show what the recursion is doing:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (mysum a)
  (cond
    ((eqv? a 1) 1)
    (else `(+ 1 (* 2 ,(mysum (sub1 a))))))) ; Notice the ` and ,
```

Here is what this does for several outputs:

```lisp
> (mysum 1)
1
> (mysum 2)
'(+ 1 (* 2 1))
> (mysum 3)
'(+ 1 (* 2 (+ 1 (* 2 1))))
> (mysum 4)
'(+ 1 (* 2 (+ 1 (* 2 (+ 1 (* 2 1))))))
> (mysum 5)
'(+ 1 (* 2 (+ 1 (* 2 (+ 1 (* 2 (+ 1 (* 2 1))))))))
```

You can view the recursive step as *substituting* the expression `(1 + 2 * rest-of-the-computation)`

Please comment or ask for clarification if there are parts that still do not make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for asking my question. I think I maybe understand it . It repeats the (1+2* mysum(sub1 a) till sub1 a equals 1 and it goes back to get the result. I never learned the Racket language so it takes time for me to read it. im sorry for  commenting  late.

Answer (score 0):

### Formula Explanation

```
1+2*(sumOf(n-1))
```

This is not a generic formula for Geometric Progression.
this formula is only valid for the case when ratio is 2 and first term is 1
So how it is working.

The Geometric Progression with first term = 1 and r = 2 will be

```
1,2,4,6,8,16,32,64
```

### FACT 1

**Here you can clearly see nth term is always equals to sumOf(n-1) terms + 1**
**Let declare an equation from fact 1**

```
n = sumOf(n-1) + 1 =======> Eq1.

Let put our equation to test

    put n = 2 in Eq1
    2 = sumOf(2-1) + 1

we know that sumOf(1) is 1 then 
2 = 2 ==> proved
```

### **so if n = sumOf(n-1)+1 then**
FACT 2

**Sum of n term is n term + sum(n-1) terms**
**Lets declare an Equation from FACT 2**

```
sumOf(n) = sumOf(n-1) + n ==> eq2
```

**let us put eq1 in eq2 i.e. n = sumOf(n-1) + 1**

```
sumOf(n) = sumOf(n-1) + sumOf(n-1) + 1 ==> eq3
```

### Simplifying

```
sumOf(n) = 2 * sumOf(n-1) + 1
```

### Rearranging

```
sumOf(n) = 1 + 2 * sumOf(n-1) ==> final Equation
```

Now Code this equation

we know sumOf 1st term is alway 1 so, this is our base case.

```py
    def sumOf(a):
        if a==1:
            return 1
```

so now sum of first `n` terms will be `1 + 2 * sumOf(n-1)` ==> From final Equation

put this equation in else part

```py
    def sumOf(a):
        if a==1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 1 + 2 * sumOf(a-1)
```